# Python sqite3 user defined queries (selecting tables)

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlite, sql-injection

I have a uni assignment where I'm implementing a database that users interact with over a webpage. The goal is to search for books given some criteria. This is one module within a bigger project.

I'd like to let users be able to select the criteria and order they want, but the following doesn't seem to work:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Books WHERE ? REGEXP ? ORDER BY ? ?", [category, criteria, order, asc_desc])
```

I can't work out why, because when I go

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Books WHERE title REGEXP ? ORDER BY price ASC", [criteria])
```

I get full results. Is there any way to fix this without resorting to injection?

The data is organised in a table where the book's ISBN is a primary key, and each row has many columns, such as the book's title, author, publisher, etc. The user should be allowed to select any of these columns and perform a search.

Comment: Probably the values for `order` and `asc_desc` are quoted by the engine, resulting `ORDER BY 'price' 'DESC'`, which is different from `ORDER BY price DESC`.

Comment: Also, in the 2nd query, you're putting in value of criteria in REGEXP? but in the first query you're putting it where "title" from 2nd query would be. Is that intentional?

Answer (score 1):

Generally, SQL engines only support parameters on *values*, not on the names of tables, columns, etc. And this is true of sqlite itself, and Python's sqlite module.

The rationale behind this is partly historical (traditional clumsy database APIs had explicit `bind` calls where you had to say which column number you were binding with which value of which type, etc.), but mainly because there isn't much good reason to parameterize values.

On the one hand, you don't need to worry about quoting or type conversion for table and column names. On the other hand, once you start letting end-user-sourced text specify a table or column, it's hard to see what other harm they could do.

Also, from a performance point of view (and if you read the [sqlite docs](http://www.sqlite.org/cintro.html)—see section 3.0—you'll notice they focus on parameter binding as a performance issue, not a safety issue), the database engine can reuse a prepared optimized query plan when given different values, but not when given different columns.

---

So, what can you do about this?

Well, generating SQL strings dynamically is one option, but not the only one.

First, this kind of thing is often a sign of a broken data model that needs to be normalized one step further. Maybe you should have a `BookMetadata` table, where you have many rows—each with a field name and a value—for each `Book`?

Second, if you want something that's conceptually normalized as far as this code is concerned, but actually denormalized (either for efficiency, or because to some *other* code it *shouldn't* be normalized)… functions are great for that. [`create_function`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.create_function) a wrapper, and you can pass parameters to that function when you `execute` it.

Comment: Wouldn't option 2 risk an injection attack?

`SELECT * FROM Books WHERE CATEGORY REGEXP ? ORDER BY ORD ASCDESC`

I can see some nasty things coming from this. The function I pass into `create_function` would need to sanitise the input, wouldn't it?

Comment: @cjdb01: Yes, `create_function` doesn't magically solve any problems, it just gives you a way to write a custom solution and then present it to the rest of the code as if it were a magic solution.

Comment: @cjdb01: But I don't understand your example. If your only parameter is a regular expression, parameter binding already takes care of everything for you, with or without a function…

Comment: @abarent I didn't mention this in the original question (which I'll update now), but I think the database is normalised at the level you suggest, since there's only one entry per ISBN (primary key). Each row has around 10 columns that relate to information such as title, author, publisher, price, etc.

I want the user to be able to select how they search, but don't want to write out all the permutations; that's why I'm leaning toward creating a function.

Comment: If you disagree and think that it can be normalised further, please let me know, since my database knowledge is two years old and is only at a high school level, where normalisation received a glossy overview.

Comment: @cjdb01: The idea is that if the field names are something to be specified programmatically, then they're _values_, and need to be treated as such. See [here](http://pastebin.com/ypQj60Vh) for example.